# Fragment not showing in home activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I added navigation drawer on map activity. Now I'm trying to add a fragment on my home activity, but fragment is not showing in activity, but code in fragment class is working.
Is my FrameLayout hiding behind the map fragment?

I'm very new to fragments.
Please help me.

**Home class layout**

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/constrain_layout"
android:orientation="vertical">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:context=".HomeActivity" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Fragment class**

```
public class RideHistory extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ride History", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ride_history,container,false);
    return view;
}
```

}

**Fragment xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.RideHistory">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Ride History" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please use [LayoutInspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) and check whether your Fragment was added to the screen (although you can't see it) Since your Fragment contains a TextView with text "RideHistory", you can search the View tree for a FrameLayout with a TextView child with the required text

Comment: I'm getting an error, layout inspector fails with a timeout error.

Comment: That's too bad, it's a great tool (when working). OK, then in order to find out whether the Fragment is hiding behind the map one can change the layout file of the Activity a little bit. For example let the map Fragment have `android:visibility="invisible"`

Comment: Not working map fragment doesn't have a visibility option.

Answer (score 0):

Change layout constraints so that both widgets frame layout and map fragment do not overlap eachother.
for ex:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    map:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/map"
    map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="434dp"
    android:layout_height="297dp"
    map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity" />
```